# How to specify reloadable="true" or reloadable="false" in Tomcat's server.xml?

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat 8.x. My website is under `/webapp/ROOT`.

I don't have any explicit `<Context>` for this website. I am looking for an example how to make reloadable="true" or reloadable="false" for this website. I searched online and know it can be set through `<Context reloadable="...">` in server.xml. However, I am not able to find an example about doing in server.xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See how an application named Booking is configured within the  in server.xml.You might also see a Valve declaration by default which is used for access logging and I just kept it there even though it doesn't matter here as you might see this in your default server.xml.

```html
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
   <Context docBase="Booking" path="/Booking" reloadable="true"   />
  </Host>
```